# How to make a 2D/nD mask: boxes around signals

Tags: arrays, matlab, 2d

I'm trying to make a 2D mask for an 2D image or in general nD mask for nD array.
So I have an array, signal positions and signal width e.g.

```
mask=ones(10,10);
pks=[[3 4]; [1 5]];
pks=sub2ind(size(mask),pks(:,1),pks(:,2)); % linear indices
xwidth=2; ywidth=3;
```

What I would like is to fill regions of size +/- x/ywidth around pks with 0.

```
mask(aroundpks)=0;
```

Certainly, I can do this with for-loops but it looks awkward, and it's probably difficult to make explicit for-loops general for nD case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask0=zeros(10,10);
mask0(pks)=1;
mask0=mask0>0;
mask0=imdilate(mask0, ones(2*ywidth+1, 2*xwidth+1))
mask(mask0)=0;
```

not sure if it is the most efficient solution but should work with ND matixes as well, just adding data on additional dimensions in the `zeros()` and `ones()` functions